# PDFMerger (PHP) is just not running - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, pdf

Hello so I have downloaded the PDF merger code for PHP from https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger/blob/master/README.md

I have my local MAMP server running and tried to run the following code to test things out:

```
<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf =  new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('Starter.pdf', '1, 3, 4');
$pdf->addPDF('Starter.pdf', '1-2');
$pdf->addPDF('Starter.pdf', 'all');

$pdf->merge('brower', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'P');
```

where .starter.pdf and PDFMerger.php are in the same folder as this code file, so the paths exist.

However, when I run this, I get a blank screen. There is no pdf.

I have tried adding 'echo: "blah"' to the bottom of the script, but nothing echos whilst  Have 'include 'PDFMerger.php' at the top either.

Fairly new to PHP and not sure what is happening.

[picture to show the blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9A1Z.png)

Comment: Follow the instructions to use Composer to install, in which case `include` gets replaced with the `use`.

Comment: Ok I will do this, but why does this change things? It's good for me to understand why so I know in the future

Comment: Provision the project as a package, it gets installed as a vendor and PHP's autoloader knows how to locate the library's resources. Installing it by downloading and copying into a directory makes this provisioning a manual process. If you look at the Apache log, you should see the error killing execution and giving you the blank response.

Answer (score 0):

// Try this, It works for me.

```
require_once "route for your files/PDFMerger.php";
use PDFMerger\PDFMerger;

$pdf =  new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('Starter.pdf', '1, 3, 4');
$pdf->addPDF('Starter.pdf', '1-2');
$pdf->addPDF('Starter.pdf', 'all');

$pdf->merge('brower', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'P');
```